# How to set a root password in yocto which has dollar($) symbol

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to set root password in my image recipe. I want to set a password which has '$' for example "abc$1234"

Following lines i have added in my image recipe

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P abc\$1234 root;"
```

When i login with 'abc$1234', it says wrong password.

Am i missing anything?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `$` twice (or even three times)?

Comment: Escaping three times worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using:

```
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p 'abc\$1234' root;"
```

Note the single quote around the passwd and a lower-case 'p'.